# Gravity manipulation i s it a possibly?

Tags: forces, gravity

I have done almost no research on the subject of "anti-gravity" (I hope it won't show too much) but I contemplate it among other kind of out there things often.  I'm reaching out to you as it looks like someone may have poked around at many of the fringes of research like this. To the point, before I lose you assuming I have you at this point.

I look at gravity as an inverse of centrifugal force and I think that is how it can be solved. I will start simple and work my way to less simple.  Imagine that amusement park ride that was like a big bowl and all the riders just leaned up against the wall..  It begins to spin picking up speed until all the riders are pinned up against the wall.  Ok hold that thought but put it aside for the moment.

Now envision that ride modified with another bowl inside of that bowl. Or a hamster wheel inside of another hamster wheel.  The inner wheel or bowl only connected to that outer bowl or wheel with beams,seals,an electric motor, sealed hollow chambered bearings and with inner chambers filled with a conductive liquid metal.  The liquid metal is only taking the place of wiring to transfer power delivered to the outer wheel and transferred to the motors that will turn the inner wheel.

So now we have the large outside wheel that can turn and a smaller inside wheel only supported by that outside wheel.  We have power to both.  Now we stand this contraption up on end more like a Ferris wheel than the original wheel we set aside earlier.  Of course we have to have anchors to the ground and supporting beams anchoring that outer wheel but we can use wires to get power to the electric motors turning that wheel.  The electric motors supported by the outer wheel are for the inside wheel that will have power transferred by the liquid metal taking the place of wires as I mentioned earlier. Wires can not twist and turn but the conductive liquid will have no problems with the motion.

I could probably take twenty pages describing this and blueprints describing it exactly but hope this email will be enough for your imagination.

For others safety sake and maybe a bit of humor I will now be the only rider.  I will go to the inside wheel and strap myself in.  You will turn the power on the wheels.  The outside wheel will go one direction fast enough that if I was strapped into that wheel I would have been held against its side.  Power is also going to the inside wheel but going the opposite direction controlled with that remote rheostat I forgot to mention, with a speed holding me against the floor of that wheel also..  The speeds will be identical adjusting for diameter differences in the wheels.  You will tweak the speed of the inner wheel until I am directly looking down toward the ground.  I will now undo my restraint and stand up.

As you look at me I am upside down and in relation to you standing still and upside down as you are standing firmly on the ground watching. I'm pretty sure I could walk a bit in that inner wheel, jump forward, backward or up and down. You could zero my artificial new floor where ever you wanted just by adjusting the rheostat and then matching the two wheel speeds again.

I call this two D gravity manipulation. Now imagine three D or Four or even five. Also imagine adding extreme electromagnetic forces to all the wheels maybe enough so that the extreme energy would supersede the effect of mass induced gravity forces.  Energy is mass but just in a diluted form after all. What would happen then? Could we unleash the outer wheel from the ground and would something magical happen assuming controls were also added by angling some ring or combination of rings?   Or..... would we just have to keep that outer wheel firmly connected to the ground and stay content with a neat magician's trick?

I am loaded with ideas like this.  Give me a shout back if anyone thinks there is any merit here.  My main concern in this brain storm is that the counteracting centrifugal forces would cancel each other out and nothing would happen.   For some unscientific reason I don't believe that to be the case.  I think I could build a miniature version for just hundreds of dollars.  Large enough to support a man or women I suspect the costs would get a bit pricey.

Comment: Hi William, first, the best of luck with your idea (s). Could you, in future, throw in a few paragraphs, as you have so much going on in your post, it can be difficult to read. I don't want people giving up on you halfway through. No offence meant, thanks.

Comment: Yes my apologies.  The original did have breaks (paragraphs)  I was in a bit of a hurry and the copy paist just did not do it justice.

Answer (score 1):

@william: Welcome to the Physics SE. Just so that you know, altering gravity is forbidden by currently known laws of physics. And no one does any such experiments anymore, at least they do not publish them. There are no budgets for gravity projects in any institutions. But there is no list of experiments that what has been tried and failed.

But you seem to be using rotation to counteract gravity, not alter it. Counteracting is not altering. When we pickup a water bottle, we counteract gravity, not alter it. rotation is same mechanism.

For all other technology, nature offers us objects and scenarios to observe and experiment with them. Just that nature does not offer same in case of gravity.

For example - (needless to say - money, materials, mathematics and manpower are essentials)

Electricity - Nature provides lightening, charge by rubbing objects etc.

Magnetism - Nature provides stones, it would have been discovered from electricity anyway.

Electronics - derived from electromagnetism

Quantum Mechanics - Add supersensitive equipment to above three and you can observe/experiment with QM

Wireless - Fire signals have been used for centuries. Everything we see, is wireless.

Aeroplanes - Watch gliding birds and can understand Bernouli's principle.

.. and so on.

In case of gravity, nature does not provide any such scenario where gravity is turned off/on. Looks like nature itself is not capable of doing so. Even if it is, it would do so in out of reach places like supernova etc. We do not know the details.

Suppose it is discovered that some massive body is on course to impact Earth in a few years, then only, every stupid idea to alter gravity will be tried out. I have my own idea for that eventuality. Otherwise, humanity is not ready for that discovery at this time.

Comment: Altering a gravitational field is trivial. Even a student can do it with almost any piece of laboratory equipment, in fact you can do it with just the student and no other equipment.

Comment: Well whereve I go, I alter the gravitational field a tiny bit. That is not altering at will. There is nothing I can do to not alter it in that case. Altering means turning it on or off (or changing its intensity like we do an electric bulb and that is without using equivalent  mass/energy.

Comment: @MartinBeckett: How do we do it, could you please describe it.

Comment: Lab experiments with gravity date back to Cavendish in 1797-98. He did it with two heavy balls in the lab. Just pull in the balls at certain distance and measure. Put them 100 Kms apart and no force is measured. You just have to not be dogmatic.

Comment: @BobBee: The question is about altering (or shielding) gravity, not measuring it. Like put the balls closer and make them not exert gravity on one another. Measuring part - yes, these experiments may be common.

Comment: kpv,  in 40 words or less Jeesh.  One large squirrel cage free to rotate and aided by a motor turning to the right.  A second smaller cage attached only to that larger cage.  (it can be done split axles in turbines use the principle)  the smaller cage rotates the opposite direction.  Does the opposing centrifugal force cancel each out and nothing turns?

Comment: disclaimer.  I'm retired and my credentials from my youth were only two associate degrees in the sciences.  My career which I just recently retired from after 35 years did allow me a great deal of lattitude with my ideas as a field rep to the engineering and developement department.  So you will not get a masters or doctorate paper from anything I write.  I mainly wanted a single question answered from all that I wrote in this discriminating forumn.  I use the word discriminating like you might if you fed a canned good during a meal to a group of culinary writers and their taste buds.

Comment: @william: Centripital force is outwards (away from center) whether the cage is rotating clockwise, or anti clockwise. So, no, they would not cancel. Centripital force is experienced by each rotating body. You can not add/subtract that for two or more bodies.

Comment: kpv, I thought it would be that way.  With out a model or a professor in front of me, I am on my own.  I however do now know I am on to something if nothing more than that magicians trick I mentioned before.  You are very understanding.  My educated career peers tolerated my ruff edges too mostly to their benefit.  You do realize the center is the same for both cages?

Comment: @william Yes the center is same, still they would not cancel.

Comment: @kpv (Suppose it is discovered that some massive body is on course to impact Earth in a few years, then only, every stupid idea to alter gravity will be tried out. I have my own idea for that eventuality. Otherwise, humanity is not ready for that discovery at this time.)  If there is a way off line or out of the general group format here I would very much appreciate hearing those ideas of yours.  William